# Java Mybatis sql inserting data in a table with composite key where both key parameter as foreign keys

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, h2, mybatis

I'm trying to make a User-Bundle relation, where the relation between them is many-many.

So, to break this many to many into 2 one-to-many, I've created another table called subscription.

The subscription table has primary keys of both user and bundle as foreign keys. The Subscription table has a composite key made of (userId,bundleId), where both these columns are not null in their respective table.

Now, when I try to insert data in the subscription table using mybatis, it gives error userId cannot be null.

The reason being, mybatis sql is converted to a prepared statement which is used for dynamic parameters.
Here's an insert statement to give you a rough idea about my subscription table

```
INSERT INTO Subscription (USERID,BUNDLEID,BUNDLESTARTDATE)
       VALUES (#{userId},#{bundleId},#{promotionStartDate});
```

Although I'm passing the userId, it doesn't accept it and calls userId cannot be null. I'm fairly sure this is due to the prepared statement. Please help.

Comment: Please show the code where you call the insert

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedNizamani Please add the output of DEBUG level log to the question.

Comment: As @ave says you can look at the runtime value you are passing for `#{userId}` by enabling the `DEBUG` level of logging. Please enable it for this query and show us the output.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I went through the logs and as expected there was an issue on my end while receiving data through api. It has been resolved though !